# mixpanel and asp.net buttons

Tags: asp.net, mixpanel

I have to add some mixpanel tracking to a good old asp.net page and it's turning into a nightmare. I have this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="idConfirmAndSubmitButton" name="confirmAndSubmitButton" Text="Confirm and Submit" OnClick="SaveAndPublishClick" runat="server" />
```

and on the .cs file have this code:

```
idConfirmAndSubmitButton.OnClientClick = "mixpanel.track('track me'); return validateFields()";
```

the event is tracked on mixpanel only if validateFields() returns false;

I've managed to reproduce the problem very simply:

this tracks properly:

```
idConfirmAndSubmitButton.OnClientClick = "mixpanel.track('track me'); return false";
```

this does not:

```
idConfirmAndSubmitButton.OnClientClick = "mixpanel.track('track me'); return true";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if `validateFields()` returns true, then the form submits, the page changes and the mixpanel code doesn't get a chance to fire. The mixpanel support suggested that I add a small delay(300 ms) to give the tracking code a chance to fire before the form is submitted. Here is the code that I ended up in the end and that seems to work:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$phMainBody$idConfirmAndSubmitButton" value="Confirm and Submit"
onclick="if(delayPostback(this,validateFields(['ctl00_phMainBody_idProfileForm']))){ console.log('stopping the postback'); return false;};" 
id="ctl00_phMainBody_idConfirmAndSubmitButton">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var postbackDelayed = false;
    function delayPostback(e, validated) {
        if (postbackDelayed) {
            postbackDelayed = false;
            return !validated;
        } else {
            postbackDelayed = true;
        }
        console.log('tracking');
        mixpanel.track('Minimum Required Fields - confirm and submit clicked');
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("clicking again");
            e.click();
        }, 300);
          console.log("returning true");
          return true;
      }
</script>
```

Some code adapted from http://forums.asp.net/t/1604156.aspx?Delay+Postback+in+Javascript